# Query to return the matching or nearest previous record by a list of dates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table of records ordered by date. There is a maximum of 1 record per day, but some days there is no record (weekends and bank holidays).

When I query a record by date, if no record exists for that day I am interested in the previous record by date. Eg:

```sql
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE date <= $mydate ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Given a list of dates, how would I construct a query to return multiple records matching the exact or closest previous record for each date? Is this possible to achieve in a single query?

The array of dates may be spread over a large time frame but I wouldn't necessarily want every record in the entire time span (eg query 20 dates spread over a year long time span).

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the dates as a derived table and then use SQL logic.  A lateral join is convenient:

```
select v.dte, r.*
from (values ($date1), ($date2), ($date3)
     ) v(dte) left join lateral
     (select r.*
      from rates r
      where r.date <= v.dte
      order by r.date desc
      limit 1
     ) r
     on 1=1;
```

You might find it useful to use an array to pass in the dates using an array and using `unnest()` on that array.

Comment: You were much faster then me, but my solution is quite similar, so I add the fiddle as comment here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=384b1dde6a264e29bb48bf3245e69b8d

Comment: Awesome. Thanks this works perfectly. Used `unnest()` and ended up needing  to cast each element to a date in the subquery, but wouldn't have got there without your answer :).